# I am trying to edit a top level window

Tags: python, tkinter

So I heard there was a method in which you could make a separate tk.Toplevel class I have been attempting to use it but I dont know exactly whats wrong I really need help
here is the code as of now I will keep trying to make adjustments but its not easy

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, title: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)

        self.label = ttk.Label(self, text="Hello, World!")
        self.label.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="Button", command=self.Alter)
        self.button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)


class ThemeWindow(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.title("NEW")
        self.parent = parent

        self.label = tk.Label(parent, text="Hello, World!")
        self.label.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.button = tk.Button(parent, text="Button", command=parent.Alter)
        self.button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
```

I have edited and used examples given in a course I am taking but clearly I am misreading.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What isn't working? Are you getting an error of any kind? Apart from some missing code, I don't see anything immediately wrong with either of these classes.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ricar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\Login.py", line 31, in <module>
    app = App("main")
  File "C:\Users\ricar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\Login.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="Button", command=self.Alter)
  File "C:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2383, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'Alter'

thats the error it shows

Comment: it doesnt run at all I dont know why

Comment: Please include the Traceback into the question by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

The key part is `AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'Alter''` - that's telling you that your `App` class (which inherits from `Tk`) has no attribute called `Alter`.

The problem is caused by your `App` class, and more specifically by `self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="Button", command=self.Alter)`

You're telling `self.button` to call the function `self.Alter` as its callback function (the `command` parameter), but you haven't defined a function called `Alter` within the `App` class.

You need to do something like this:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, title: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)

        self.label = ttk.Label(self, text="Hello, World!")
        self.label.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.button = ttk.Button(
            self, 
            text="Button", 
            command=self.alter  # don't  use uppercase in function names!
        )
        self.button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

    def alter(self):  # define a function 'alter' within this class
        print('Hello')  # do whatever you need this function to do here
```

Now when `button` is pressed, it will be able to call `alter`, which (in this case) should print "Hello"

Likewise, your `ThemeWindow` class should be able to call this via `parent.alter`

*Again, note that I've changed the name from "Alter" to "alter" to adhere to Python naming conventions.*

Comment: it does work but the button is not opening a new window

Comment: You didn't say that's what you wanted the button to do. If you want the button in your `App` class to open the window created by your `ThemeWindow` class, modify the `alter` method to instantiate the `ThemeWindow` class - for example, replace the `print` statement with something like `self.window = ThemeWindow(self)`

Answer (score 0):

> you could make a separate tk.Toplevel class I have been attempting to use it but I dont know exactly whats wrong

> > it does work but the button is not opening a new window.

The problem can be fixed.

As @JRiggles pointed out that you have a typo error, the name from **Alter** to **alter**.

In class `ThemeWindow`. You cannot use parent for widgets. Otherwise, it will not show on GUI widgets. So use `self` instead of `parent`.

- Add second class module inside alter() function.
- You cannot have  both keyword command for the same function.
  Otherwise, it creates a new duplicate Toplevel window.
- Add class `ThemeWindow` inside `alter()` function.
- Add close_window function inside class `ThemeWindow`

Snippet slight minor changed:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, title: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)

        self.label = ttk.Label(self, text="Hello, World!")
        self.label.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="Button" , command=self.alter)
        self.button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

    def alter(self):
        ThemeWindow(self)

    
class ThemeWindow(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.title("NEW")
        self.parent = parent

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Hello, user20309839")
        self.label.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Button", command=self.close_window)
        self.button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

    def close_window(self):
        self.destroy()

        
if __name__=='__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    app = App('Main Window')
    root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:
[image]